# How to pattern match a scala immutable queue?

Tags: scala

I want to use `immutable.Queue` and in particular

1. I want to access the head of the queue without dequeuing it. Immutable queue is implemented using two immutable lists/stacks, and from the code it looks like this operation is not constant time (see this [line](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/cd50464cd019bc6a489a72b98293c30b91352bab/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala#L80)), although dequeue is (amortized constant time). Can someone confirm or correct me?
2. I like the pattern matching syntax for `List` (e.g., `list match { case head :: tail => ... }`). Do we have something similar for `Queue` as well?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the general purpose matcher `+:` on `Seq`:

```
val q = Queue.empty[Int]

q match {
  case x +: xs => // non-empty case
  case _ => // empty case
}
```

You can also use `Queue`'s `unapplySeq`:

```
q match {
  case Queue(x, _*) => // non-empty case
  case Queue() => // empty case
}
```

Note that both of these are potentially more inefficient than `Queue.head`, since they have to construct the dequeued Queue as well, which is only `O(1)` in amortized time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer of `+:`. I see that it comes from `SeqExtractors` class.

Comment: My first question still holds: Is `Queue.head` really `O(1)`? I modified my question to include a link to the source code.

Comment: No, it is not. If you hit the line you mentioned, you will have to go over the `in` List. An immutable dequeue like that is amortized `O(1)` since you `enqueue` and `dequeue` every element exactly once (which is also not necessarily true, implement by `dequeue` and discarding the result queue). Since you can do `head` multiple times, the particular `head` you are querying might not be amortized.

Comment: IIUIC per your reply, the answer text is a bit incorrect regarding `Queue.head` is `O(1)` amortized. Could you fix that? Thanks!